# How to make aws s3 bucket public but strict it to specific domain and localhost (testing)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How to make aws s3 bucket public but restrict it to specific domain and localhost:3000 (for testing purpose).

Basically the s3 files will be accessed by the react.js website and we don't want the s3 files to be accessed outside the wwww.example.com domain and localhost:3000

Tried couple of things but doesn't seem to work.

[image]

Bucket policy - Not configured and not sure what to specify

[image]

Let me know the changes to be done to make it work.

Comment: Can you tell us more about how the files will be accessed? What do you mean by "accessed by the react.js website" -- how is that code accessing objects in Amazon S3?

Answer (score 0):

> How to make aws s3 bucket public but strict it to specific domain

Its not possible. At best you could [Restricting access to a specific HTTP referer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4), but its not bullet proof. AWS writes:

> Therefore, do not use aws:Referer to prevent unauthorized parties from making direct AWS requests.

You need proper authoritative mechanism and place your website behind some login screen, if you want to control access to it.

Comment: It's behind a login screen but still want additional security. Can you let me know if there is any other way

Comment: @Sharath With S3 there is not much else you can do. Maybe just limit access to your website to a single IP or IP range. You can also keep it private, and use CloudFront in front of your S3.  But then, what's the point of making it public in the first place if you don't want anyone to access it?

Comment: For ex: When a confidential pdf file is loaded in the website (after login) the user can copy the link of the file and pass it to others. So we don't want the file to be viewed/accessed outside the website.

Comment: @Sharath Use s3 presigned urls. But then your users can just send the pdf files themselfs, or post on other websites in they can download it.